# How to check the md5sum and sha256sum of a directory (an entire folder)?

Tags: command-line, directory, md5sum, sha256

In the terminal it's easy to find the md5sum of a single file, but how about for an entire directory? And would the same apply to sha256sum?

Answer (score 5):

This little script will make sha512sums of a folder and all its subfolders and save it to a file called sha512checksums:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
rm -f sha512checksums
find -type f ! -iname "sha512checksums" -exec sha512sum "{}" + > sha512checksums
```

And this following scrip lets you check the sums based on the before created file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
rm -f sha512errors
sha512sum -c sha512checksums 2> sha512errors 1>/dev/null
if [ -s sha512errors ]
then
  echo The following errors where found while checking:
  more sha512errors
  rm -f sha512errors
else
  echo All files are ok.
  rm -f sha512errors
fi
```

Same will work as well for every other sum making algorithm, you only would have to alter the scripts.

Comment: So when you said "every other sum making algorithm" you mean sha256sum also and not just sha512sum like you used?

Comment: `md5sum`,  `sha1sum` till `sha512sum`, just alter the code accordingly.

Comment: Ahh. So is this the same method BitTorrent clients use when checking the integrity of a downloaded folder with contents inside?

Comment: Kinda, just a bash script to do the checking locally.

Comment: Does this actually output the filenames into the sha512errors file? My system only seems to output the number of failed files in STDOUT.

Comment: the file only will contain errors, if there are no errors the file will be empty, and anyways removed at the end.

Comment: If you want output leave the `1>/dev/null` out

Comment: @Videonauth cool! is there a way to make this to do it to compare two folders? Where do you inser the folder path? in {}?